# Caffe conv layer weights and dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I came across this nice [article](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/) which gives an intuitive explanation of how convnets work.

Now trying to understand what is going on exactly inside a caffe conv layer:

With input data of shape 1 x 13 x 19 x 19, and 128 filters conv layer:

```
layers {
  name: "conv1_7x7_128"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  blobs_lr: 1.
  blobs_lr: 2.
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 7
    pad: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      }
      bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      }
    }
}
```

Layer output shape is 1 x 128 x 19 x 19 if i understand correctly.

Looking at the layer's weights' shapes in `net->layers()[1]->blobs()`:

```
layer  1: type Convolution  'conv1_7x7_128'
  blob 0: 128 13 7 7
  blob 1: 128
```

Looks like blob 0 has all the weigths: one 7x7 matrix per plane (13) per filter (128).

Doing convolutions with blob 0 on 1 x 13 x 19 x 19 data, if i understand correctly we end up with 128 x 13 x 19 x 19 output (there's padding so each 7x7 matrix produces one number for each pixel)

- How does 128 x 13 x 19 x 19 turn into layer's 1 x 128 x 19 x 19 output ?
- What are the 128 weights in blob 1 ?

Bonus question: what is `blobs_lr` ?

Comment: a simple google of about the bonus question led me to Cf. MNISTtutorial for why people use 2 different strategy for learning rate:
blobs_lr are the learning rate adjustments for the layer’s learnable parameters. In this case, we will set the weight learning rate to be the same as the learning rate given by the solver during runtime, and the bias learning rate to be twice as large as that - this usually leads to better convergence rates.
 https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting an older version of caffe's prototxt format. Adjusting to new format will give you

```
layer {  # layer and not layer*s*
  name: "conv1_7x7_128"
  type: "Convolution"  # tyoe as string
  param { lr_mult: 1. }  # instead of blobs_lr
  param { lr_mult: 2. }  # instead of blobs_lr 
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 7
    pad: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      }
      bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      }
    }
}
```

If you have input data of `shape` 1 x 13 x 19 x 19, means your `batch_size` is 1, you have 13 channels with spatial dimensions of 19 x 19.
Applying 128 filters of 7 x 7 (each filter is applied to all 13 input channels) means you have 128 filters of `shape` 13 x 7 x 7 (this is the `shape` of your first layer's parameter). Applying each filter results with a *single* output channel 1 x 1 x 19 x 19, since you have 128 such filters you end up with 1 x 128 x 19 x 19 output.

The second layer's parameter is the *bias* term - an additive scalar to the result of each filter. You can turn off the bias term by adding

```
bias_term: false
```

To the `convolution_param` of you layer.

You can read more about convolution layer [here](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/convolution.html).

As for the bonus question, Eliethesaiyan already answered it well in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750133/caffe-conv-layer-weights-and-dimensions/44753437#comment76487553_44750133).

Comment: Thanks, this is beginning to make sense. It explains why `blobs_lr` isn't mentioned in the doc: `lr_mult` [replaces it](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4896). I think what i'm missing is, within one filter how the outputs from the 13 7x7 kernels get combined into one. I guess they're just added together ?

Comment: @lemonsqueeze a *single* filter has 13x7x7 parameters "sliding" across the 13x19x19 input blob. Each 13x7x7 patch produces a *single* scalar stored in the corresponding location in the output blob. Applying the single 13x7x7 filter to the entire padded input results with 1x19x19 output. Your layer has `num_output: 128` thus you have 128 different filters each producing a 1x19x19 slice. The layer simply concat the 128 slices into a single output blob 128x19x19. (The leading `1x` dim is the "batch size" I ignored it here for simplicity)

Comment: Ok, i get it. I thought 2D convolutions were taking place while actually each filter is just one 3D convolution, the 3rd dimension being the different planes. To get back to the [article](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/), we're not sliding a square but a cube of numbers across the entire input space.